# Clarification on solution to a problem:

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

The problem is as follows:

How many zeroes do we write when we write all the integers from 1 to 243 in base 3?

The given solution starts as follows:

The 1-digit numbers don't have any zeroes.

The 2-digit numbers use 2 zeroes: 10 and 20.

There are $3^2 = 9$ three-digit numbers starting with 1 and 9 starting with 2. 
For each leading digit, a zero appears in each digit in 9/3 = 3 of the numbers, 
so each has a total of 3+3 = 6 zeroes.
Thus, the 3-digit numbers contain 2*6 = 12 zeroes.

I do not understand how they arrived with the fact that

"for each leading digit a zero appears in 9/3 = 3 of the numbers"

and why they are multiplying the result by 2 to get 12 at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half of the three-digit numbers start with **1**; the other half start with **2**. Consider those that start with **1**. The 'middle' digit (to the left of the leading 1) can be a **0** in three different cases: when the rightmost (least significant) digit is **0**, **1** or **2**. Similarly, the rightmost digit will be **0** for the three values (**0**, **1**, **2**) that the middle digit will take on. Thus, for the three-digit numbers starting with **1**, we use a total of 6 zeroes. The same calculation applies for the three-digit numbers with a leading **2**. This gives us a total of $2*6 = 12$ zeroes in the three-digit numbers.